# Set transparency (alpha) of area chart openpyxl

Tags: python, openpyxl

I want to set transparency to the background of an area chart using openpyxl. The code I have for the chart is:

```
from openpyxl.drawing.fill import PatternFillProperties, ColorChoice

c2 = AreaChart()
c2.grouping = 'stacked'
c2.add_data(data, titles_from_data=True)

c2_s1 = c2.series[0]
fill = PatternFillProperties()
fill.background = ColorChoice(srgbClr="FFFFFF")

c2_s2.graphicalProperties.pattFill = fill
```

I have tried using rgba hexadecimal encoding.

```
fill.background = ColorChoice(srgbClr="80FFFFFF")
```

I have also try to use `SystemColor` but I could not find any example of how to use it and every attempt I made was unsuccessful

Answer (score 2):

Extend ColorChoice

```
from openpyxl.compat import unicode
from openpyxl.descriptors import Typed
from openpyxl.descriptors.serialisable import Serialisable
from openpyxl.descriptors.nested import NestedInteger
from openpyxl.xml.constants import DRAWING_NS


class MyRGBColor(Serialisable):
    tagname = 'srgbClr'
    namespace = DRAWING_NS
    val = Typed(expected_type=unicode)
    alpha = NestedInteger(allow_none=True)
    __elements__ = ('alpha', )

    def __init__(self, val, alpha=None):
        self.val = val
        self.alpha = alpha


class MyColorChoice(ColorChoice):
    srgbClr = Typed(expected_type=MyRGBColor, allow_none=True)
```

..and

```
c2_s1.graphicalProperties.solidFill = MyColorChoice(
        srgbClr=MyRGBColor('0000FF', alpha=50000))
```

Answer (score 1):

> **From the Docs**:
>       Values must be of type `class openpyxl.drawing.effect.AlphaBiLevelEffect`

[search PatternFillProperties](http://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/default/search.html?q=PatternFillProperties&check_keywords=yes&area=default)
[PatternFillProperties](http://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/default/api/openpyxl.drawing.fill.html?highlight=PatternFillProperties)
Come back and Flag your Question as answered if this is working for you or comment why not.

Comment: could you kindly reply to my latest post with an example please? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that what you want to do isn't currently possible without modifying openpyxl source. See ["this pull request"](http://bitbucket.org/openpyxl/openpyxl/pull-requests/166) for further information.