# Creating complex Area Chart using openpyxl (transparency)

Tags: python, openpyxl

I am trying to create an area chart using openpyxl. I wish for the area chart to look more complex than the basic excel charts. Here is my data

data

```
month   group1  group2
jan     15      13
feb     19      15
mar     20      17
apr     25      24
may     29      30
jun     24      30
jul     16      40
aug     20      24
sep     22      20
oct     27      17
nov     17      26
dec     21      29
```

[image]

Desired

[image]

Doing

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl.chart import BarChart, Reference, Series, ScatterChart, LineChart, StockChart, AreaChart, AreaChart3D



path = "C:/Users/thud/wb1.xlsx"
wb_obj = load_workbook(path)
sheet_obj = wb_obj.active



c1 = AreaChart()
c1.title = "Area Chart"
c1.y_axis.title = "Cost"
c1.x_axis.title = "Date"
c1.x_axis.number_format = 'mm/dd/yy'
c1.x_axis.majorTimeUnit = "days"
c1 = deepcopy(c1)
c1.style = 39


data = Reference(sheet_obj, min_col=2, min_row=2, max_col=3, max_row=13)
c1.add_data(data, titles_from_data=True)

dates = Reference(sheet_obj, min_col=1, min_row=2, max_row=13)
c1.set_categories(dates)


sheet_obj.add_chart(c1, "I2")
wb_obj.save("sample.xlsx")
```

I have found this in the documentation, but unsure of how to implement:

```
     openpyxl.drawing.effect.AlphaBiLevelEffect
```

I'd like to add transparency to the area chart and have it reflect my desired output.
Any suggestion is appreciated

Comment: I got the transparency working by following this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51006976/15161640 , but I couldn't get the gradientFillProperties working yet.

Comment: @MarkH could you please post your answer/response. Transparency is the goal , not necessarily gradient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Transparency working, with SO link of source in code:

```python
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl.chart import BarChart, Reference, Series, ScatterChart, LineChart, StockChart, AreaChart, AreaChart3D
from copy import deepcopy

path = "wb1.xlsx"
wb_obj = load_workbook(path)
sheet_obj = wb_obj.active

c1 = AreaChart()
c1.title = "Area Chart"
c1.y_axis.title = "Cost"
c1.x_axis.title = "Date"
c1.x_axis.number_format = 'mm/dd/yy'
c1.x_axis.majorTimeUnit = "days"
c1.style = 39

data = Reference(sheet_obj, min_col=2, min_row=2, max_col=3, max_row=13)
c1.add_data(data, titles_from_data=True)

dates = Reference(sheet_obj, min_col=1, min_row=2, max_row=13)
c1.set_categories(dates)

########## BEGIN INSERT

#### BEGIN CUSTOM CLASS
#### https://stackoverflow.com/a/51006976/15161640
from openpyxl.drawing.colors import ColorChoice
from openpyxl.descriptors import Typed
from openpyxl.descriptors.serialisable import Serialisable
from openpyxl.descriptors.nested import NestedInteger
from openpyxl.xml.constants import DRAWING_NS

class MyRGBColor(Serialisable):
    tagname = 'srgbClr'
    namespace = DRAWING_NS
    val = Typed(expected_type=str)
    alpha = NestedInteger(allow_none=True)
    __elements__ = ('alpha', )

    def __init__(self, val, alpha=None):
        self.val = val
        self.alpha = alpha

class MyColorChoice(ColorChoice):
    srgbClr = Typed(expected_type=MyRGBColor, allow_none=True)
#### END CUSTOM CLASS

# A list of colors - add more to handle more series
colors = ["0000ff","ffa500"]
color_gen = (c for c in colors)

# set a pattern for the whole series
for series in c1.series:
    clr = next(color_gen)
    aclr = MyColorChoice(srgbClr=MyRGBColor(clr, alpha=50000))
    series.graphicalProperties.solidFill = aclr
    series.graphicalProperties.line.solidFill = clr

########## END INSERT

sheet_obj.add_chart(c1, "I2")
wb_obj.save("sample.xlsx")
```

Comment: Let me try @markH - also would you know the answer to my latest post?

Comment: The chart titles and axis labels aren't behaving for me, even with the examples straight from the tutorial.  I'm using openpyxl 3.0.7 and LibreOffice 6.4.6.2.  I might be able to look into this later.

Comment: Actually, they look good in Google Drive, so LibreOffice must be the problem.